# drupal_render($node_view); is not working

Tags: nodes, entities

Node page is not loading once I add below code

```
 drupal_render($node_view);
```

I was referring https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/node_view/7 
and added below code in my `node--type.tpl.php`

```
<?php
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $node_view = node_view($node);
  $rendered_node = drupal_render($node_view);
  echo $rendered_node;
?>
```

Comment: are you sure $nid has value ?

Comment: yes.i declared  $nid=$node->nid . If i hard code node id of type of itself the page is not loading, if i give node id of other types the page is loading.

Comment: you want to get views data?

Comment: i want to print node content in a particular view mode

Comment: Can you define "not working"? What happens? A white screen, a timeout, an error message? Is there something relevant in the Apache/PHP/Drupal logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have the Drupal sources at hand right now, I didn't digg into it yet. But I'm pretty sure the node_view() function is using your node--type.tpl.php for rendering its output.

So calling it within your template will lead to a recursion. You might want to check on that.

Comment: Good point. But it would only lead to recursion if the node loaded with `node_load($nid)` is of the same bundle as the "type" in `node--type.tpl.php`, right?